# store P12 on public datacenter securely

Tags: hashicorp-vault

We have a lot of user P12 files (certificates) for each clients/tenant and we would like to store it securely. We don't use cloud solution like Amazon, Azure Keyvault or other datacenter solution but a hosting company.

Do you have any solution ? Vault from Hashicorp

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vault to manage your own PKI and issue certificates instead. In fact, it is more than that,

From [using Hashicorp Vault to manage PKI and issue certificates](https://medium.com/@sufiyanghori/guide-using-hashicorp-vault-to-manage-pki-and-issue-certificates-e1981e7574e)

> Vault allows you to manage an entire Public Key Infrastructure (PKI)
>   to ensure secure communication among different services. This allows
>   companies to easily setup their own certificate authority (CA), revoke
>   or issue new certificates using simple API calls, thus dumping the
>   painful process of constantly generating self-signed certificates.

You can checkout [this guide](https://medium.com/@sufiyanghori/guide-using-hashicorp-vault-to-manage-pki-and-issue-certificates-e1981e7574e) for the process of using Vault to generate and issue certificates.